# Matlab function with many inputs of different types

Tags: matlab, function

What is the best way of passing several (more than 20) variables of different types and size to a function?

These variables are of types number, string, vector, matrix and cell.

Currently this is the way I am dealing with it:

```
% BEGIN main m-file
...
parameter1=
parameter2=
.
.
.
Func1
% END main m-file
```

my function:

```
function Func1
parameter1=evalin('base','parameter1');
parameter2=evalin('base','parameter2');
.
.
.

% do something

end
```

I am wondering if there is a better approach for this?
Thank you

Comment: What kind of size are your vectors and matrices ?

Comment: Cell Array, i guess. There are plenty of examples with it on SO.

Comment: 1X2 and 2X3 usually!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use `structs` when passing large amounts of parameters to a function. If you have a large number of regular parameters, it might be better to use a vector or cell array, but for mixed parameters [structures](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) are more convenient, and you can give the field-names useful names:

```
options.gain = 5.432;
options.offset = 1.23;
options.title = 'Just a straight line';
options.matrix = [1, 2; 3, 4];
```

And you would define your function like this:

```
function do_something(options, x)
y = options.gain * x + options.offset;
plot(x, y)
title(options.title)
```